# Install ECP Only - Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

I need to be able to edit Exchange attributes in my onPrem AD. How can I install Exchange ECP only.

Using Exchange Online with one way sync OnPrem-> Exchange Online

Answer (score 0):

I think you may install the Exchange management tools, it contains Exchange Admin Center(ECP) and Exchange Management Shall(EMS). Then you could gain a full control of your exchange server.
[Install the Exchange management tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/post-installation-tasks/install-management-tools?view=exchserver-2019)